# Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ is it true that:"If $R$ is not an integral domain then also $R/I$ isn't an integral domain"?``

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

The question:
Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Is it true that if $R$ is not an integral domain then also $R/I$ isn't an integral domain?

My attempt at solution is the following:

I don't think the claim is true.
As a counterexample I take $R=6\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ I believe that $R/I=3\mathbb{Z}$ which is an integral domain, while $R$ isn't an integral domain since it has zero divisors.

I am not sure, if I got it right.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right. The claim is definitely not true. In fact, for any commutative ring $R$ with identity and ideal $I$ of $R$, the ring $R/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is prime. In particular, if you take a prime ideal $P$ of a non-integral domain $R$, then $R/P$ will always be an integral domain

Comment: In the future, always replace "the question is in the title" with the actual contents of the title. Nobody wants to read "the question is in the title" and everybody wants a self-contained post body. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose, $R=\Bbb{Z_6}$ and $I =\{0, 3\}$

Now, $R/ I \cong Z_3$ which is an integral domain.

Hence, $R/ I$ integral domain doesn't imply $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

In any non trivial ring $R$ there exists a maximal ideal $M$. Then $R/M$ is a field, so in particular it is an integral domain.

Comment: I know, but what would you do without it?